# Using complex schema with AJV

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I'd like to reuse object properties in Ajv schema, but it claims that some part cannot be resolved:

```
const Ajv = require("ajv@8.11.0").default

const ajv = new Ajv({
  strictSchema: false,
  loadSchema: async (uri) => {
    console.log(uri);
    switch (uri) {
        case "main":
            return {
                entity: { $ref: "entity" },
                request: { $ref: "request" }
            }
        case "entity":
            return {
              type: "object",
              properties: {
                id: {type: "string"}
              },
            }
        case "request":
            return {
              type: "object",
              properties: {
                id: {$ref: "main#/entity/properties/id"}
              },
            }
    }
  },
})

const validate = await ajv.compileAsync({
    $ref: "main#/request"
})

validate({
 id: "123"
})
```

produces error: `Error: AnySchema main is loaded but main#/entity/properties/id cannot be resolved`

while replacing `main#/entity/properties/id` with `entity#/properties/id` makes it work. What I am missing?

Live code: https://runkit.com/desofto/64a40e034daec80008a495b5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` schema is precisely this:

```js
{
  entity: { $ref: "entity" },
  request: { $ref: "request" }
}
```

The JSON Pointer `#/entity/properties/id` doesn't resolve to a location within `main`.

It looks like you're expecting the JSON Pointer to resolve the `{ $ref: "entity" }` at `main#/entity`, but JSON Pointers don't resolve references.

---

The code you posted may just be an example to illustrate your point, but given that `entity#/properties/id` is just

```json
{ "type": "string" }
```

it may just make more sense to repeat that in your `request` object rather than trying to reference into `entity` to get it.  Typically references don't extract subschemas that way.  They *can*, but it's not advised to do so.

If you'd really like to reference it, I suggest you extract that out into a new schema and reference it from both places.

Another option is to [compose](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html) all of these into a single schema and make use of `$defs` to house any reusable pieces.

Comment: Thank you Greg, it seems that referring entity directly is the only way to solve my problem.